# Change colour of MeshStyle in Plot3D

Tags: plotting

I have the following code that makes a 3D plot, with 3 Mesh functions drawn on top of it:

```
um = 1;
Potential[V0_, k_, w_, x_, z_] := V0*(Sin[k z]^2)*Exp[(-2 x^2)/w^2] 
Plot3D[Potential[1, (2 \[Pi])/(0.725 um), 1 um, x, z], {x, -2.1 um, 
  2.1 um}, {z, -1.1 um, 1.1 um}, PlotRange -> Full, 
 AxesLabel -> MaTeX /@ {"x/\\sigma"}, PlotPoints -> 50, 
 Mesh -> {{0, 0.5, 1}, {2}, {2}}, 
 MeshStyle -> {{Red, Blue, Green}, {Red}, {Blue}}, Boxed -> False, 
 Axes -> {True, False, False}, PlotStyle -> Cyan, 
 Ticks -> {Table[i, {i, -2, 2, 1}]}]
```

How can I make the three Mesh functions have different colours?

I tried the `MeshStyle -> {{Red, Blue, Green}, {Red}, {Blue}}` but all 3 functions end up Green...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the option `MeshFunctions -> {# &, #2 &, #3 &}` and specify individual styles for mesh divisions using option `Mesh`:

```
Plot3D[Potential[1, (2 π)/(0.725 um), 1 um, x, z],
 {x, -2.1 um, 2.1 um}, {z, -1.1 um, 1.1 um}, 
 PlotRange -> Full, PlotPoints -> 50, 
 MeshFunctions -> {# &, #2 &, #3 &}, 
 Mesh -> {Thread[{{0, 0.5, 1}, {Red, Blue, Green}}], 2, 2}, 
 MeshStyle -> {Automatic, Orange, Purple}, Lighting -> "Neutral", 
 Boxed -> False, Axes -> {True, False, False}, PlotStyle -> White, 
 Ticks -> {Table[i, {i, -2, 2, 1}]}]
```

[image]

**Notes:**

I your code, the `Mesh` specs `{2}` for the  second and third directions is outside the plot range.

Default value of the `MeshFunctions` for `Plot3D` is `{#1 &, #2 &}`

```
Options[Plot3D, MeshFunctions]
```

> {MeshFunctions -> {#1 &, #2 &}}

so the mesh in the vertical direction will not be drawn unless you use the option `MeshFunctions` with setting `{#&, #2&, #3&}`.

[`MeshStyle >> Details`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshStyle.html)

> - MeshStyle->{Subscript[g, 1],Subscript[g, 2], ...} *specifies that successive directives Subscript[g, i] should be used cyclically to draw elements associated with successive mesh functions.*

So you cannot specify different directives for individual mesh divisions corresponding to a given mesh function. To style mesh divisions individually you can use the form `{{{mesh1, directive1}, ...}, ...}` as the setting for the option `Mesh`.